# Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am assigning a class property from the database like so (Checks for session go on prior to this but this is just the assignment):

```
$stmt = DB::getInstance()->Prepare(
    'SELECT id, username, email FROM _users WHERE session = ?'
);

$stmt->execute(
    array( $this->session( 'oauth' ) )
);

$this->_user = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
```

The `$_user` property may be altered through other parts of the program thus it needs to be passed by reference:

```
public function &getUser() : Object { return $this->_user ?? (object) array('username' => 'Guest'); }
```

The issue I am having now is that when I make a call to `getUser` to update the user properties:

```
$request->getUser()->posts = array('example post'); // This is done on another class, sometimes there is no reason to load the users posts if the user is not visiting a page that needs that data
```

I get this notice:

```
Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference
```

So to go ahead and do what it says (pass it by reference), I then store the `$_user` by reference like so:

```
$this->_user =& $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
```

I then get this error (on the above line):

```
Uncaught Error: Typed property App\Http\Request::$_user must not be accessed before initialization
```

Any ideas how I can suppress this warning or why it is showing up?

Comment: Did you actually mean `array('example post') = $request->getUser()->posts;` because otrherwise it does make no sense

Comment: The `$_user` is initialised in the `Request` class. The `Request` class is then passed by reference to the `Controller` class based on the route, ie `/users`. The `Controller` class then manipulates the `$_user`, in this case, appends all of the users posts to the `$_user->posts` so that when the view is loaded, all the user data is there.

Some views do not need the user post data, so to reduce page load time etc etc, the controller can manipulate what data is needed for that page. Does that make more sense in what I'm trying to achieve? @B001ᛦ

Comment: It works as expected, I can `var_dump($request->getUser()->posts)` in my view and see the posts, the only issue I'm getting is this annoying notice @B001ᛦ

Comment: Okay,thanks for the explanation.  I'd try to first assign `(object) array('username' => 'Guest')` to a variable and then return that variable

Comment: How did I not see this! I thought that the notice was coming from the assignment `$request->getUser()->posts` not from the `getUser` method itself. That fixed my issue after removing the `?? (object) array('username => 'Guest')`! If you want to create an answer, I'll mark it! @B001ᛦ

Comment: Glad I could help ;) Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment expressions always return the assigned value.

Change:

```
public function &getUser() : Object { 
    return $this->_user ?? (object) array('username' => 'Guest'); 
}
```

To:

```
public function &getUser() : Object { 
    $obj = (object) array('username' => 'Guest'); // <-----
    return $this->_user ?? $obj; 
}
```

by assigning the object to a variable and return this variable.

Comment: The only issue here is that `$obj` would be set to the default `(object) array(...)` each time `$request->getUser()` is called. To fix this, I moved the reference into  where the DB query is made and did a check there: `if( !isset( $this->_user->id ) ) { $this->_user = (object) array( 'username' => 'Guest' ); }` but the logic fixed my notice! Thanks again!

Comment: The issue is that `$obj =` [rewrites every time](https://3v4l.org/XBM8u). It needs to be set outside the `getUser()` execution, [like so](https://3v4l.org/f2drQ). Your logic is spot on, just breaks the functionality setting the second value inside the call to `getUser`